# RealmSwift and Swift 2.1 (module file was created by older version of compiler)

Tags: realm, swift2, xcode7.1

I searched and got answers on using CocoaPods but really i couldn't manage to use it because i didn't what they mean

1- Install CocoaPods 0.39.0 or later. -> i did install it using sudo command

"I stopped here, didn't know what to do"

2- In your Podfile, add use_frameworks! and pod 'RealmSwift' to your main and test targets.

3- From the command line, run pod install.

4- Use the .xcworkspace file generated by CocoaPods to work on your project!

sorry my question looks bad but it is my first time to ask a question here :)

Comment: Share your entire Podfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of steps is correct, and assuming CocoaPods installed correctly, you will then need to navigate to the directory of your `.xcodeproj` file.

In that directory, you can run the command `pod init` which will create a `.podfile` in the directory.

You can then continue onto steps 2-4.

However, as of writing this response, Realm's current release doesn't support Swift 2.1. We are actively working on an update for 2.1, which you can follow on this [Github Issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2716).